# Prevent fetch git tags from remote with refspec

Tags: git

How can I prevent `git fetch` to fetch tags from one remote (`upstream`) by default?

Is there a *refspec* setting that can make `git fetch upstream` equal to `git fetch -n upstream` ?

I don't want to inadvertently fetch tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [configuration documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)

> remote.<name>.tagOpt
>
> Setting this value to `--no-tags` disables automatic tag following when fetching from remote `\<name\>`. Setting it to `--tags` will fetch every tag from remote `\<name\>`, even if they are not reachable from remote branch heads. **Passing** these flags directly to git-fetch **can override** this setting. See options `--tags` and `--no-tags` of git-fetch.

So yes, you can configure git NOT to fetch tags *by default* for a specific remote name.

---

Example:

If we run the following command: `git config --local remote.upstream.tagOpt --no-tags`, then in our repo `.git/config` we would have

```
[remote "upstream"]
        tagOpt = --no-tags
```

Where you have the freedom to set this configuration locally per repo, or for your user (under `/home/user/.gitconfig`) or for your whole system.

Comment: ✅ So I can use **`git config --local remote.upstream.tagOpt --no-tags`**

Comment: Exactly. I'll edit my answer to provide an example how it will look